# How do I continually update a mysql database driven webpage?

Tags: mysql

How would i populate a page with data that is pulled from a mysql database and have the content update as the data in the database updates?

Answer (score 0):

How would i populate a page with data that is pulled from a mysql database:

Its very generic question :) You will need a webserver and host an application on that server which connects to database and fetches the results and parses them in html for clients.

If you want to update the page once database is updated , you can use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or HTML5 websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Periodically poll the main page, or use long polling, which leaves the request open until the new data is ready to be sent back.